# bootstrap max-width content in tables issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

`img {
max-width: 100%;`

this is breaking content namely the images shrink down in my bootstrap based template - I cant get a reason why this is.

content is a table with rows and some icon images such as

```
<table>
  <tr class="sectiontableentry2 even" id="tree_row_26">
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">4</td>

    <td id="jlms_step_26" valign="middle" width="20"><img alt="accept" border=
    "0" class="JLMS_png" height="16" src="../lms_images/toolbar/btn_accept.png"
    width="16"></td>

    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="16">
      <div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
        <span style="text-align:center;"><img alt="content" border="0" class=
        "JLMS_png" height="16" src=
        "http://demo1.bwood1.wok.catn.com/components/com_joomla_lms/lms_images/files/file_content.png"
        width="16"></span>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td align="left" colspan="1" valign="middle" width="100%"><a href=
    "javascript:seek_step_id=26;ajax_action('lpath_seek');">Automation
    criteria</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `max-width: 100%` prevents images from growing outside the containing structure. If you're running into to that for a `td` you need to increase the width of the `td` so that the image fits. This is definitely by design.

Answer (score 0):

The width of all your rows together is more than the width of the table.

Only set the width of the table and of the columns with a fixed width.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr class="sectiontableentry2 even" id="tree_row_26">
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="20">4</td>

    <td id="jlms_step_26" valign="middle" width="20"><img alt="accept" border=
    "0" class="JLMS_png" height="16" src="../lms_images/toolbar/btn_accept.png"
    width="16"></td>

    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="16">
      <div style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">
        <span style="text-align:center;"><img alt="content" border="0" class=
        "JLMS_png" height="16" src=
        "http://demo1.bwood1.wok.catn.com/components/com_joomla_lms/lms_images/files/file_content.png"
        width="16"></span>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td align="left" colspan="1" valign="middle"><a href=
    "javascript:seek_step_id=26;ajax_action('lpath_seek');">Automation
    criteria</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqVyu/

*Next time, please ask as 'why is this happening' or 'what am I doing wrong' to prevent getting down voted. Because the question on itself is valid.*

Comment: Thanks - I think people should be careful with downvoting as I am banned from asking questions for some reason. And it's an automated process to get unbanned. It's a year on now and so am I ! But thank you all for contributing to this question.

Answer (score 0):

A good fix from @_pier is:

`table td img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}`